# Getting posts from wordpress returns the same result when present in several cathegories

Tags: mysql, wordpress, distinct

In the home page of a website I need to return the last 3 posts of the blog, created with wordpress.

I have this code:

```
SELECT p.post_title, p.post_date, p.post_content, wpr.object_id, dt_blog_terms.name,        dt_blog_terms.slug
FROM dt_blog_terms
INNER JOIN dt_blog_term_taxonomy ON dt_blog_terms.term_id = dt_blog_term_taxonomy.term_id
INNER JOIN dt_blog_term_relationships wpr ON wpr.term_taxonomy_id = dt_blog_term_taxonomy.term_taxonomy_id
 INNER JOIN dt_blog_posts p ON p.ID = wpr.object_id
 WHERE taxonomy = 'category'
 AND p.post_type = 'post'
 AND p.post_status = 'publish'
 AND slug != 'notizie-notifiche'
 ORDER BY `post_date` DESC
 LIMIT 3
```

As you can see, I have one cathegory (notizie-notifiche) that I want to exclude. This sql string works, but I have a problem when the post has more than one cathegory. In this case, it is returned once for every cathegory, while I want to show it only once in total.

Any idea?
I thought I could use DISTINCT, but it does not seem to work with this kind of SELECT statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can tell you what you need to do, but I can't modify the query to do it.  You use the term "category" in your question, but there is no field by that name in your data.

You need to aggregate your data, at the level you want, and then include a `having` clause.  The following `group by` may solve your problem:

```
group by p.id
having sum(case when slug = 'notizie-notifiche' then 1 else 0 end) = 0
```